# What/where are the most recent JAVA libraries and dependencies for the Google Gmail API?

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

There seems to be some mismatch in the documentation on the Google Developers website, and I'm not clear what to download and what to add to my IDE for the most recent stable version.

If I go to [this downloads page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/gmail/v1), the Gmail-API is version 1.25.   Unfortunately, the [setup documentation here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup#generic_java) lists some libraries which are not present in that download (such as commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, httpcore-4.0.1.jar, jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar, protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar, xpp3-1.1.4c.jar).

If, instead, I follow the above setup documentation instructions, I am taken to [this page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download) which is clearly version 1.24.  ...but the JavaDoc documentation seems to be [for version 1.25.](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/)

Alternatively, if I look on Github, I can see that the latest Google Client API for Java [is 1.28](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/releases), - so I'm guessing that dependency for Gmail API hasn't updated to yet.

Are these libraries being retired in favor of something else?  Is that why the dependencies and docs are out of date?   I just want to add the correct jars to my IntelliJ IDE and send a couple of messages.

Comment: Do you even need the gmail jar to send emails from java? why not just java mail?

Comment: @zack6849 There are a lot of nice features included in the jars, things such as searching, that Google has spent time "optimizing" and would be wasteful to re-implement.

Comment: If you are using Gradle(Which is great, i recommend it), you simple need to add the line: `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev101-1.25.0'`

Comment: I am not using Gradle.  I would also prefer not to go to JavaMail route as the next phase in the program will likely use some of the APIs more advanced features.

Comment: @Dylan, can I just download the jar that's listed [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev101-1.25.0)?

Comment: Click in the link "See all versions available on the Maven Central Repository." https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.google.apis%20AND%20a:google-api-services-gmail And the latest now is: v1-rev20190422-1.28.0

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of back and forth in your explanation.
You are talking about two different libraries - The Google API Client and the Gmail API.
Each one of them have different versions, they are not correlated.

Regarding the difference in the version between -

> If instead I follow the above setup documentation instructions, I am taken to [this page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download) which is clearly version 1.24.

and

> Alternatively, if I look on Github, I can see that the latest Google Client API for Java is 1.28

Now the difference is minor 1.30.2 & 1.30.1 not sure why, But still either one should work just fine.

---

And to answer your question, the most recent Gmail API is stated here - 
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/

But in order to send an email using the Gmail API, You need to authenticate & authorize the sending of the email. This is done using the [Google API Client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)

This API will prompt the user to login and authorize access to certain actions and requests within his account. These actions and requests can be invoked by Different APIs such as the Gmail API.

If you want to send emails using a simple command line, you should probably read more about using an SMTP Server. Gmail offers extensions for this [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/).